# One of my cookies set with Javascript always comes up null. The rest read fine

Tags: javascript

Link to code to test: https://jsbin.com/modocelume/edit?js,console

One of my cookies are always coming up null. The rest read fine. In the actual application, it's meant to read URL parameters. In that scenario, I can actually change which one is null, but it's always at least one!

I can see the cookie is set in the developer tools, it's not HTTP Only, and the expiration is fine.

Anyone have any experience with this?

```
var urlParams = [
  'utm_source', 
  'utm_medium', 
  'utm_campaign', 
  'utm_term', 
  'utm_content'
];

function createCookie(name, value, days, domain) {

  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = '; expires=' + date.toGMTString();
  } else {
    var expires = '';
  }

  if (domain) {
    var domain = '; domain=' + domain;
  }

  document.cookie = name + '=' + value + expires + domain + '; path=/';
}

function readCookie(name) {

  var name = name + '=',
      fields = document.cookie.split(';');

  for(var i=0; i < fields.length; i++) {

    var field = fields[i];

    while (field.charAt(0)==' ') {

      field = field.substring(1, field.length);

      if (field.indexOf(name) == 0) {

        return field.substring(name.length, field.length);
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

urlParams.forEach(function(param) {

  createCookie(param, param, 365, '');
});

urlParams.forEach(function(param) {

  console.log(readCookie(param));
});
```

I expect the output for `readCookie('utm_source')` to be `utm_source`, but the output is `null`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This code in dev toolbar works fine, I'm getting all the cookie values. Is your issue that you get `null` even in dev toolbar?

Comment: Here's a longer version of the script doing (mostly) what it's supposed to do: http://www.everythingiscute.com/?utm_source=source&utm_term=term&utm_medium=medium&utm_content=content&utm_campaign=campaign

But I'm still getting the utm_source as null. https://imgur.com/By5VT97

The cookie gets created, I just can't read it. It comes up null in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, your `utm_source` field name did not have an empty space in front of it, so your `while (field.charAt(0) === ' ')` didn't fire for it. I changed it to below code and it seems to be working fine now:

```
function readCookie(name) {

  var name = name + '=',
      fields = document.cookie.split(';');

  for(var i=0; i < fields.length; i++) {

    var field = fields[i].trim();

    if (field.indexOf(name) == 0) {

       return field.substring(name.length, field.length);
    }

  }
  return null;
}
```